# How to simplify testing a string against multiple regexes

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate if string is spotify or youtube or invalid URL. This works, but it seems it could be done simpler. How can I make it more efficient?

```
String.prototype.spotifyUrl = function() {
  return this.match(/^(spotify:|https:\/\/[a-z]+\.spotify\.com\/)/);
}

String.prototype.youtubeUrl = function() {
  return this.match(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?$/);
}

function validateUrl (url) {
  if ( url.spotifyUrl() ) {
    alert('spotify');
  } 
  else if ( url.youtubeUrl() ) {
    alert('youtube');
  }
  else {
    alert('invalid url');
  }
};

validateUrl('https://open.spotify.com/track/3JiockjOTd8m2VGcTGkmew');
```

**[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qg9oo0xq/)**

Comment: why so complicated regex for `youtube`?

Comment: I'd leave it as it is, you need the logic to decide what the regex is referring to. Go for the simpler solution and save your time.

Comment: if it is only for validation purpose, use  `RegExp.prototype.test` instead of `String.prototype.match` and `/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?youtu(?:\.be\/|be\.com)\//` should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You could make an object with a property per site you want to recognise:

```js
var sites = {
    spotify: /^(spotify:|https:\/\/[a-z]+\.spotify\.com\/)/,
    youtube: /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?$/,
};

function validateUrl (url) {
    for (var site in sites) { 
        if ( url.match(sites[site]) ) return site;
    }
};

// I/O:
var div = document.querySelector('div');
var input = document.querySelector('input');

input.oninput = reportValidation;

function reportValidation() {
    div.textContent = validateUrl(input.value) || 'invalid url';
}
reportValidation();
```

```html
Type URL:<br>
<input type="text" size="60" value="https://open.spotify.com/track/3JiockjOTd8m2VGcTGkmew">
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose is to **just check** the origin of URL then shorter will be to check only for `spotify.com` or `youtu.be` or `youtube.com`.

```js
function validateUrl(url) {
  if (url.match(/spotify\.com/)) {
    alert('spotify');
  } else if (url.match(/youtu\.be|youtube\.com/)) {
    alert('youtube');
  } else {
    alert('invalid url');
  }
};

validateUrl('https://open.spotify.com/track/3JiockjOTd8m2VGcTGkmew');
```

Comment: It's less efficient than the original pattern (because not anchored).

Comment: I imagine the reason he's using a more complex regex is that, for example, "spotify.com" might appear anywhere in the URL, _e.g._ a referring URL in the query string.

Comment: As you might have noted youtube video URL don't have other URL embedded in them. So this is just a rough or shorter way to check the origin of URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need separate returns that depend on Spotify versus YouTube, then you can just combine the regular expressions with `|`, and forget about the String prototype function:

```js
function validateUrl(url) {
  if (url.match(/^(spotify:|https:\/\/[a-z]+\.spotify\.com\/)|^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?$/)) {
    alert('valid');
  } else {
    alert('invalid url');
  }
};

validateUrl('https://open.spotify.com/track/3JiockjOTd8m2VGcTGkmew');
```